# image and containing table not displaying

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage I'm working on that has a few shapes and an overlaid image all within container tables.

This looks fine in Firefox and Chrome but the entire right column gets cropped down to a small row in Safari.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/colej4586/4pXXG/42/

I'm thinking maybe this is the CSS that is causing it but I really have no idea.

```
 .overlay {
/* Pull the content up over the banner */
margin: 5% 0 0% 0%;
padding: 1em;
color:white;
/* Using this will make sure that it goes over the element, not under */
position: relative;
/*z-index:4;*/
width:80%;    
}
```

Comment: few people doing safari debug here i think

Comment: Thank you, but I guess I should also add it displays the same way in safari on my mac as it does in firefox on windows

Comment: You have a lot of code in the fiddle. Can you trim it down to the minimum required to see the problem? That will make it easier to diagnose. And maybe you will find out yourself where the problem area is.

Comment: By the way, if the problem occurs with Safari under Windows but not on a Mac, it's probably due to the Windows version being outdated. (Safari Windows only goes up to v5.1.7) Do you have some very new CSS or HTML features in there?

Comment: Thanks @Mr Lister. I guess that probably is why Firefox isn't displaying it properly. Also I've found that removing:
    'overflow:hidden;' 
in the css of the right container.
Also, I was using VW for the dimensions of the shapes and also tried using % as well. The only thing that seems to work to get these to display is px, which I don't entirely understand. Guess I'll use px, though.